# Projection methods for solving $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I try to get an intuitive understanding of projection methods to solve an algebraic system like $Ax=b$.
So instead inverting the matrix  $A$ we choose a constraint spaces $C_i \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n $ and  search spaces $S_i \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$.
Then, iteratively, we try to find $x_i \in  x_0 + S_i $ such that $b-Ax_i \perp C_i$ with 
$$S_i \subseteq S_{i+1} \text{ and } C_i \subseteq C_{i+1}.$$ In my understanding, it looks like, we try to "chop-off" subspaces from the residual until its dimension attains zero. But I am not sure, if that is the idea of it or there is another way to see it. Thanks!

Comment: What projection method are you talking about?

Comment: The framework of projection-methods seems to be the foundation from which we can derive CG-method and similar methods. For example here on page 11: http://user.it.uu.se/~maya/Courses/NLA_Parallel/Slides_2013/NLA_CG_Parallel_Psli.pdf